# Is it possible to keep an object always to front during the execution of the program?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I need to keep an object always to front in `UIView`

without interfering this action

```
- (IBAction)botonArribaMenu:(id)sender {

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_propArribaRegresar];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any of the following UIView methods to control depth.

```
– bringSubviewToFront:
– sendSubviewToBack:
– insertSubview:atIndex:
– insertSubview:aboveSubview:
– insertSubview:belowSubview:
```

Each superview stores its subviews in an ordered array and the order in that array also affects the visibility of each subview. If two sibling subviews overlap each other, the one that was added last (or was moved to the end of the subview array) appears on top of the other.